# Using a Join query with ignited datatables trying to get a where with two conditions

Tags: sql, codeigniter, datatables, where-clause

I am attempting to pull data from mysql database using codeigniter and ignited datatables. I have no troubles pulling the join query with a single where clause, but when I try to add a WHERE x OR y, I can't seem to get it working. Here is the basic code that works fine:

```
$table = 'test_base';
$table2 = 'lab';
$this->datatables->select('test_base.idlab');       
$this->datatables->from($table);
$this->datatables->join($table2, 'test_base.idlab = lab.idlab');
$this->datatables->where('lab.idaccount',$idaccount);
```

If I wanted to put multiple conditions in the query, I see from the [manual](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki/Function-Reference) that I can put multiple conditions in an array, but this seems to only do an AND, not an OR statement.

I then see that I may be able to create my own sql query using the following:

```
$this->datatables->where('column != "string"');
```

So, I tried this:

```
$this->datatables->where("`lab`.`idaccount`= $idaccount OR `lab`.`idlab` = 0");

SELECT `test_base`.`idlab`
FROM (`test_base`)
JOIN `lab` ON `test_base`.`idlab` = `lab`.`idlab`
WHERE `lab`.`idaccount`=` 124 OR `lab`.`idlab` = 0
ORDER BY `idtest` asc
```

The issue is that there is an extra (`) in the WHERE `lab`.`idaccount` = `<-here and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: why you don't try directly your sql query with $this->db->query($your_query_string);

Comment: I finally found another spot that may resolve it, but currently have a working example. I'm posting this in case it might help others. $this->db->where('string_query', NULL, FALSE); The FALSE prevents CI from putting backticks to protect tables. Found here under custom string: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ehecatl suggests, I got it working by entering the full query into the (). There were no examples on the CodeIgniter website or anywhere else I could find. Still new to CodeIgniter so maybe this will also help others.

Resolution is to put the query string in the $this->datatables->where(); and removing all the single quotes.

```
$this->datatables->where("lab.idaccount = $idaccount OR lab.idlab = 0");
```